# angular *ngFor binding to arrays Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to write a single component to render arrays to the template . It should be fairly basic . But I am not sure why it's throwing error with RC.4 . 
﻿

```
import {Component, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from "../common/shared/header/header.component";
import {SidenavComponent} from "../common/shared/sidenav/sidenav.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.component.html',
    providers: [],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, HeaderComponent, SidenavComponent],
    pipes: []
})
export class Home {
    names: Array<string>;

    constructor() {
      this.names = ["Alex Tuder",
            "Pedro Montoya",
            "Hal Jordan",
            "Tony Stark"];

    }
}
```

The Html template -

```
<table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>                                                                             
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let name of names">
                                        <td> {{name}}</td>                                           
                                    </tr>    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Package.json--

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

It worked previously with other times . But I am not sure why is it throwing error .Now .

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/grsN559mvepVYHqF6axD

Comment: I think, It should work

Comment: I get a similar error when I upgraded a rdash-ui template to angular 2.0.0